# Spread operator is not working in react typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using React + typescript and encountered with a problem regarding rendering a component.

Here is the code of what I have tried

```
filterCellComponent = ({ column, ...restProps }) => (
        <TableFilterRow.Cell
            column={column}
            {...restProps} />
    );
```

In the above method, i use the {column} variable to perform some conditions and then I render the  with use of {...restProps}. But I am getting a syntax error saying some props are missing. But when I debug, all the props that are required are inside the {...restProps} variable. I do not understand why this is happening.

Here is the image that shows the error:
[image]

And this is the error message that i'm getting
[image]

Any idea on why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: I think its not an error,may be its a warning

Comment: What are the propTypes accepted by `Cell`? The issue here is that `filterCellComponent`'s signature doesn't declare any types. It's type usage is not deterministic, so TS assumes `any`. You need to declare it as accepting the Cell's propTypes.

Comment: On a different note, why do you need `filterCellComponent` when it's not seem to be doing anything. Simply use `Cell` instead.

Comment: @hazardous you are correct, by specifying the type for the props, it solved the syntax issue. thanks a bunch!

Comment: @hazardous i actually simplified the method for better understanding. It's supposed to performs some logic and render few components based on certain conditions

Comment: @SajadJaward Makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems as if typescript cant determine the type of `column`. Try specifying the types in the function signature like this:

```
filterCellComponent = ({column, ...restProps}:InsertTypeHere) => (
```

To clarify, the problem is that `filterCellComponent` right now accepts any object that has a column-property. But `TableFilterRow.Cell` wants `column` to be a specific type.